# Another exercise about nbd-finite family (Dugundji III. 9.2)

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{A} =\{ A_{n} \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ a family of sets in $X$ such that $A_{n+1} \subset A_{n}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that, if $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{A_{n}} = \emptyset$, then the family $\mathcal{A}$ is nbd-finite.

A family $\{A_{\alpha} : \alpha \in \mathcal{A} \}$ is nbd-finite in $Y$ if for each point $y$ in $Y$, exist $V$ in $\mathcal{N}_{y}$ such that $A_{\alpha} \cap V \neq \emptyset$ for at most finitely many indices $\alpha$.

I'm trying to prove by contradiction, but I can not get something absurd. (i.e. I suppose that $\mathcal{A} =\{ A_{n} \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ isn't nbd-finite, then there is a point $x \in X$, such that the set $\{ A_{n} \in \mathcal{A} \ | \ A_{n} \cap V \neq \emptyset \}$ is not finite, for each $V \in \mathcal{N}_{x}$.)

Will I be able to come to a contradiction with this hypothesis?

Comment: Another term is "locally finite". A family $ F$ of subsets of a space is locally finite iff every point has a nbhd that intersects only finitely many members of $F.$.... BTW a useful theorem is that if $F$ is a locally finite family of  $closed$  sets then $\cup F$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

We argue the contrapositive. Suppose $x\in X$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects infinitely many elements of $\mathcal{A}$. We aim to show that $x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{A_n}$.
To this end, fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $x$. By hypothesis there exists $m\ge n$ such that $U\cap A_m\ne\emptyset$. Since $A_m\subseteq A_n$, we deduce $U\cap A_n\ne\emptyset$. Consequently $x\in\overline{A_n}$. Therefore $x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{A_n}$.